# OOP Database lookup table

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

First i want to tell you that i am new to OOP concept, but i like to learn this in order to survive to this OOP world :).
So, i just have a project, data entry asp.net web form application. I want to separate this app in 3 layers (is first time).
I have my database in place, now i make my dto's in order to exchange objects state between layers.
I don'T know how to repreaent the lookup tables values in my classes?!
Let's say I have the following tables:

```
Patient table

PatientID int
PatientName varchar
PatientStateID int (fk States table)

State table

StateID int (pk)
StateName varchar
```

Now i have the Patients class DTO

```
public class Patient
{
 public int PatientID {get; set;}
 public string PatientName{get;set}
 // and now the problem
 How to represent State property?
 public int PatientStateID {get; set;}
 public string StateName {get; set}
}
```

For this i know, i have i stored proc in sql that make the join and return all the needed data.
But is ok? Or i need to make classes for that lookup tables too?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the State like so:

```
public class Patient
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public State MyState {get; set;}
}
```

**EDIT**: changed the Setter clause to give correct syntax

And you can refer to `Patient.MyState.Statename` for example to get the desired info.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So in my State class i need to have a method (constructor) that retruns the state name an initialise in this way Patient.MyState = new State(Patient.StateID);? Rememer i am new to OOP!

Comment: @gligom When you define the Patient class in the way I suggested, the State will be instantiated at the moment you instantiate the Patient. Just try this construct annd step trhough the code. You will see it happening. (If applicable, please mark my answer as correct)